# Backend Wordpress Product Search without spaces

Tags: woocommerce

Please!! I'm having trouble with a website woocommerce backend product search. I work with products with alfa numeric titles so I'm trying to look for a code that let me search without spaces, for example Item: Antenna-RRT-4000 (I want to search RRT4000 and it's not letting me) It shows no products but if I type RRT 4000, shows the items I'm looking for. I try with diferent plugins (relevansi and others) and nothing.. Thnanks in advance!!!

Is it posible to do it with code like this in the fuctions.php?? this one is broken is it posible to fix it?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', function ($search_fields ) {
$posts = get_posts( $terms ); {
$new_terms = array();
if ( $terms ) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( preg_match( "/[\d]+/i", $term ) ) {
            if ( preg_match( "/\b([^\d\W]+)([\d]+)\b/i", $term, $matches ) || preg_match( "/\b([\d]+)([^\d\W]+)\b/i", $term, $matches ) ) {
                if ( strlen( $matches[1] ) > 1 ) {
                    $new_terms[] = $matches[1];
                }
                if ( strlen( $matches[2] ) > 1 ) {
                    $new_terms[] = $matches[2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ( ! empty( $new_terms ) ) {
        $terms = array_merge( $terms, $new_terms );
    }
}
return $terms;
```

}

Comment: Hi there, are you wanting to search for products or orders? The filter you are using is for orders you see, perhaps that could be the issue?

Comment: Thak you for replying, i need to search for products.. That is certainly the problem! Im going to find out what I need yo change. Thak you again for leting me know.

Comment: As I didn't provide code to solve the problem, I wrote my thoughts as a comment. I am glad you found it of use! If you have solved the issue, a good way of contributing to stack overflow is writing an answer below with the code you used to fix the issue, then marking it as the correct answer for completeness. Have a good day!